# how can i join a two tables admin_role and admin_user in magento grid function _prepareCollection

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I just tried to get collection for two tables in magneto using function for _prepareCollection.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/user_collection');
        $collection->getSelect()->join( array('table_alias'=>$this->getTable('admin/admin_role')), 'main_table.user_id = table_alias.user_id', array('table_alias.*'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

but its showing syntax error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to print select statement to see table alias for admin user collection table and then use it instead of `main_table`

To do this, write following statement.

```
echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```